# Cannot get UIBarButtonItem to display with UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a `UIToolbar` and I'm trying to just add a label to display different messages. I've looked at a few examples on how to do this and it's pretty straight forward. To do it, I created two properties, 1 for a `UIBarbuttonItem` and 1 for the label. However, when trying to add the `UILabel` to the to the bar button item's custom view, neither the button item or label are visible. But if I comment out adding the label to the custom view, the default bar button item will show up.

Here's the code I added to viewDidLoad...

```
self.toolbarButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStylePlain;
[self.toolbarButtonLabel sizeToFit];
self.toolbarButtonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.toolbarButtonLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.toolbarButton.customView = self.toolbarButtonLabel;
```

Nothing displays as a result of the last line, but if I comment out that line, the default style bar button item will display.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above code it works fine.

It means the toolbarButton is not set as navigation item. Try this :

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem: self.toolbarButton]  ;
```

Also, make sure that navigationItem is non null.

Comment: That added a bar button item to the upper right corner of the navigation bar, not the toolbar. However, it did also make the bar button that I wanted on the toolbar appear (even without commenting out the custom view line). But it didn't add my label to it.

Comment: I tried the same code in toolbar and that worked too.

Comment: Can you check add more code of how are you setting up your toolbar button ?

Comment: That's the entire code other than the fact that I dragged a UIBarButtonItem (self.toolbarButton) onto the toolBar in storyboard.

Comment: Still couldn't figure out why this wouldn't work, but I took a slightly different approach...dragged a UIView onto the toolbar in storyboard and created an outlet, which made it a UIBarButtonItem outlet, and dragged a UILabel onto the UIView and created another outlet. From there had no problem setting everything and making it visible.